# ListBoxItem ContextMenu only when ListBox Multiple Items Selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I disable the listboxitem context menu when none or only one item is selected?

ListBox has a `SelectedItems` property, but it is read only and you cannot bind to it.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="GOGO" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="GOGO" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Adding two `DataTrigger`s checking whether the `SelectedItems.Count` is 0 or 1 in which case it sets the `ContextMenu` to `{x:Null}`.

Comment: How to show a different `ContextMenu` when `SelectedItems.Count > 1` ?